# Rails - Check if post exists, special characters seems to mess things up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, string, if-statement

I've got a model and I want to send data to the db if the entry doesn't exist.

I'm using this code and checks if the name exists in the db.

```
if(!FeedEntry.exists? :name => entry.title)
FeedEntry.create!(...)
end
```

But the thing is that when special characters appear, like

```
âåäö
```

it sometimes doesn't find a post even though it exists, do I need to convert it to make sure the string doesn't exist in the db?

Answer (score 0):

Tell Ruby to use UTF-8 by adding `# encoding: utf-8` to the beginning of your file.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not do

```
FeedEntry.find_or_create_by_name ( "âåäö" )
```

I don't know if it would help with your special character problem, but it looks clearer.